# What is the correct path for this css file?

Tags: css, path

I'm trying to write the proper path for my css. But I can't figure out the proper way to write it. I want to connect this css file : homepageStyle.php to this file /7questions/index.php

Here's what I wrote : href="css/homepageStyle.php

```
And here's the actual path :
/public_html
index.php
/css
/7questions
   index.php
   /css
     /homepage
        homepageStyle.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.php` instead of `.css`.

Comment: Yes but I use this header at the beginning : <?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

Comment: Why not simply use .css, no need for opening `<style>`